# Error when compiling maven on hadoop-intellij-plugin

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, intellij-idea

I'm just getting start on hadoop and trying to compile Hadoop-Intellij-Plugin using maven, however some errors occurred during the execution of

```
mvn assembly:assembly
```

Could somebody help me with that?

And here are the error info:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/30545/Desktop/HadoopIntellijPlugin-master/src/main/java/com/fangyuzhong/intelliJ/hadoop/options/ProjectSettingsManager.java:[26,17] ?????
  ??:   ?? scheme()
  ??: @interface com.intellij.openapi.components.Storage
[ERROR] /C:/Users/30545/Desktop/HadoopIntellijPlugin-master/src/main/java/com/fangyuzhong/intelliJ/hadoop/fsconnection/ConnectionManager.java:[38,25] ?????
  ??:   ?? scheme()
  ??: @interface com.intellij.openapi.components.Storage
[ERROR] /C:/Users/30545/Desktop/HadoopIntellijPlugin-master/src/main/java/com/fangyuzhong/intelliJ/hadoop/fsbrowser/FileSystemBrowserManager.java:[38,79] ?????
  ??:   ?? scheme()
  ??: @interface com.intellij.openapi.components.Storage
[ERROR] /C:/Users/30545/Desktop/HadoopIntellijPlugin-master/src/main/java/com/fangyuzhong/intelliJ/hadoop/core/ui/tab/TabbedPane.java:[16,8] com.fangyuzhong.intelliJ.hadoop.core.ui.tab.TabbedPane?????, ?????com.fangyuzhong.intelliJ.hadoop.core.dispose.Disposable??????isDisposed()
[ERROR] /C:/Users/30545/Desktop/HadoopIntellijPlugin-master/src/main/java/com/fangyuzhong/intelliJ/hadoop/globalization/LocaleLanguageManager.java:[78,93] ?????
  ??:   ? Adapter
  ??: ?? com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectLifecycleListener
[ERROR] /C:/Users/30545/Desktop/HadoopIntellijPlugin-master/src/main/java/com/fangyuzhong/intelliJ/hadoop/core/ui/ValueSelector.java:[347,13] ?DumbAwareAction??????
  com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbAwareAction ????? DumbAwareAction(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.swing.Icon) ? com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbAwareAction ????? DumbAwareAction(java.util.function.Supplier<java.lang.String>,java.util.function.Supplier<java.lang.String>,javax.swing.Icon) ???
[ERROR] /C:/Users/30545/Desktop/HadoopIntellijPlugin-master/src/main/java/com/fangyuzhong/intelliJ/hadoop/core/ui/ValueSelector.java:[369,13] ?DumbAwareAction??????
  com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbAwareAction ????? DumbAwareAction(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.swing.Icon) ? com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbAwareAction ????? DumbAwareAction(java.util.function.Supplier<java.lang.String>,java.util.function.Supplier<java.lang.String>,javax.swing.Icon) ???
[ERROR] /C:/Users/30545/Desktop/HadoopIntellijPlugin-master/src/main/java/com/fangyuzhong/intelliJ/hadoop/core/ui/ValueSelector.java:[583,38] ?????
  ??:   ?? getBorderColor()
  ??: ? com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil
[ERROR] /C:/Users/30545/Desktop/HadoopIntellijPlugin-master/src/main/java/com/fangyuzhong/intelliJ/hadoop/fsconnection/ConnectionCache.java:[80,93] ?????
  ??:   ? Adapter
  ??: ?? com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectLifecycleListener
[ERROR] /C:/Users/30545/Desktop/HadoopIntellijPlugin-master/src/main/java/com/fangyuzhong/intelliJ/hadoop/options/DefaultProjectSettingsManager.java:[80,93] ?????
  ??:   ? Adapter
  ??: ?? com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectLifecycleListener
[ERROR] /C:/Users/30545/Desktop/HadoopIntellijPlugin-master/src/main/java/com/fangyuzhong/intelliJ/hadoop/options/DefaultProjectSettingsManager.java:[83,9] ???????????????
[INFO] 11 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.353 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-23T13:55:53+08:00
```

Comment: can you post the relevant code? To ask questions more accurately look here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just found another way to implement Hadoop on Intellij, thanks anyway:)